# How do you say "recognized authority" as in "recognized authority in a field of study"?

Tags: translation

I've been searching for the specific way to say "recognized authority" as in "recognized authority in a field of study". I intend to use it as a label, like "John (recognized authority)".

I've been able to find 定評 in jisho, but it seems to mean more "reputation" than "recognized authority" in the sentences I've found.

Anything with the same meaning will also be appreciated.

Comment: Would 「専門家」 do? https://jisho.org/search/%E5%B0%82%E9%96%80%E5%AE%B6

Comment: That's a really nice option too, but I wanted to make the "recognized" and "authority" both explicit (and for that , separated), as it kind of are the two main points of the said label description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common phrase would be 「世界的権威{せかいてきけんい}」 if one is among the best in the field.

There is 「著名{ちょめい}な権威」, but it is not nearly as common as the above.  In case one is just relatively well-known without being among the most, it would be a more appropriate phrase than the first one above.

Though 「世界的権威」 does not directly contain "recognized", but it is more than implied because if you are not recognized, you will not be 世界的.

Much less common and/or less natural-sounding phrases would include:

「よく知られた権威」、「有名{ゆうめい}な権威」、「認知{にんち}された権威」, 「定評{ていひょう}のある権威」, etc.